# What type of primer should be used on moisture resistant drywall?

Tags: drywall, mold, primer, moisture

What type of primer should I use my basement bathroom walls? New moisture resistant drywall has been installed, taped and sanded, and is now ready to be primed.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple, don't waste $$$ on fancy primers.  For new drywall, do not use high hiding or shellac based primers. Use PVA sealer/primer. Amen! See my other answers on primers and sealers.

Answer (score 3):

Any quality primer with mold/mildew resistance.

Answer (score 1):

[BIN primer](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Zinsser-B-I-N-1-Gal-Shellac-Based-White-Primer-Sealer-182406/202016525#.UX_4Q8ojs-A)

I am guessing this is for a bathroom.  Always good to get a good primer but the top coat of paint is way more important.  Sherman-Williams makes a Bath Paint(?).  It has a 5 year warranty for mold/mildew.  I am sure there are many other similar kinds but this is what I have used.  Also if you want moisture out of your walls, high-gloss is the best and flat is the worst...

Comment: Also (and quit reading if you are on the green team) an oil based paint with at least a semi-gloss - couple coats - is almost bullet proof in a bathroom.  It will also allow you to clean up dust/dirtiness.

Comment: Good luck trying to by oil based interior paint. Last time I was at the Sherwin-Williams store they mentioned that they are not allowed to make it anymore and they are only allowed to sell what is left in their stock.